# How to enable switch button by clicking switch button in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I need to enable and disable (A) switch button when clicking (B) switch button.
I try many ways to fix this but I can't. I try using the checked option in the switch but it doesn't work.

I have two switch buttons. The first one is (A) the Second one is B as an example. firstly I want to disable the B switch button already. Then I press the A switch button(value - true) B switch button must be enabled. it was working on my code. Then I click the B switch button (value - true) and I click the A switch button (value - false) In that case B switch button must be (value - false) I need to know how to do this

when I pressed (benefitEnabled) switch button I need enable the (benefitRequired) switch button and if I disable the (benefitEnabled) switch (benefitRequired) switch button will be disabled.
my Code

```
            <Col span={2}>
                <Form.Item
                    {...this.props.field}
                    name={[this.props.field.name, 'benefitEnabled']}
                    fieldKey={[this.props.field.fieldKey, 'benefitEnabled']}
                    valuePropName="checked"
                    initialValue={true}
                >
                    <Switch
                        disabled={this.props.isAuth}
                        checkedChildren={<CheckOutlined/>}
                        unCheckedChildren={<CloseOutlined/>}
                        onChange={this.enableButton}
                    />
                </Form.Item>
            </Col>
            <Col span={2}>
                <Form.Item
                    {...this.props.field}
                    name={[this.props.field.name, 'benefitRequired']}
                    fieldKey={[this.props.field.fieldKey, 'benefitRequired']}
                    valuePropName="checked"
                >
                    <Switch
                        disabled={!this.props.isAuth && this.props.productBenefitDetailsDto.benefitRequired ? false  :true }
                        // checkedChildren={<CheckOutlined/>}
                        // unCheckedChildren={<CloseOutlined/>}
                        checked={this.state.checked}
                        onChange={this.enableButton2}
                    />
                </Form.Item>
            </Col>
```

my class

```
interface Prop {
    productBenefitDetailsDto: ProductBenefitDetailsDto;
    srccTcCodeList: Array<SrccTcCodeDto>;
    tcCodeList: Array<TcCodeDto>;
    srccTcGroupItem: WrapperListItem
    required: boolean;
    enable: boolean;
    field: any;
    isAuth: boolean
}

interface State {
    openCollapse: boolean;
    srccTcCodeList: SrccTcCodeDto
    tcCodeList: TcCodeDto
    tcRates: any
    srccRates: any
    availableTc: boolean
    availableSrcc: boolean
    loading: boolean,
    dropdownLoading: boolean
    checkedType: boolean
    applicableType:boolean
    checked:boolean
}

const columns = [
    {title: 'Benefit Amount', dataIndex: 'benefitAmount', key: 'benefitAmount'},
    {title: 'Core Benefit Code', dataIndex: 'coreBenefitCode', key: 'coreBenefitCode'},
    {title: 'Benefit Min Amount', dataIndex: 'benefitMinAmount', key: 'benefitMinAmount'},
    {title: 'BenefitLimit', dataIndex: 'benefitLimit', key: 'benefitLimit'},
    {title: 'Excess Amount', dataIndex: 'excessAmount', key: 'excessAmount'},
    {title: 'Excess Prem Limit', dataIndex: 'excessPremLimit', key: 'excessPremLimit'},
    {title: 'Vehicle Age From', dataIndex: 'vehicleAgeFrom', key: 'vehicleAgeFrom'},
    {title: 'Vehicle Age To', dataIndex: 'vehicleAgeTo', key: 'vehicleAgeTo'},
]

export class BenefitComp extends React.Component<Prop, State> {
    constructor(prop: Prop) {
        super(prop);
        this.state = {
            loading: false,
            dropdownLoading: false,
            openCollapse: false,
            tcRates: "",
            srccRates: "",
            availableTc: false,
            availableSrcc: false,
            srccTcCodeList: {description: "", benefitCode: ""},
            tcCodeList: {description: "", benefitCode: ""},
            checkedType: false,
            applicableType : true,
            checked:true
        };
    }

    openCollapse = () => {
        this.setState({openCollapse: !this.state.openCollapse});
    };

    enableButton = (checked: boolean) => {
        console.log("OOOOOP : ",checked)
        if (checked == true){
            this.props.productBenefitDetailsDto.benefitRequired = false
            console.log("value switch if : ",this.state.checkedType, this.props.productBenefitDetailsDto.benefitRequired)

            // @ts-ignore
            // this.enableButton2()

        }else {
            this.props.productBenefitDetailsDto.benefitRequired = checked
            console.log("value switch else : ", this.state.checkedType,this.props.productBenefitDetailsDto.benefitRequired)
            // @ts-ignore
            this.enableButton2(false)
        }
    };

    enableButton2 = (checked:boolean) => {
            this.setState({
                checkedType:checked
            })
        console.log("checked : ",this.state.checkedType)
    };
```

Help to fix this issue

Comment: You need to simpler your question by providing enough code to focus on your problem.

Comment: I have two toggle buttons. The first one is (A) the Second one is B as an example. firstly I want to disable the B toggle button already. Then I press the A toggle button(value - true) B toggle button must be enabled. it was working on my code. Then I click the B toggle button (value - true)  and I click the A toggle button (value - false)  In that case B toggle button must be (value - false)  I need to know how to do this

Comment: It's about the code you provided. I get your question, but you need to edit your question's code in the simplest way instead. E.g, I don't know what is your _toggle button_ means.

Comment: toggle button means <Switch> in antd sorry for that

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the codes you've shared.

### Important

> Can you please share which ***component library*** you're using?. I
> can be wrong but *I assuming you are using **Material UI (MUI)***.
> This can help to give more context about the handlers and the right
> way how to update the component props, following the lib
> documentation.

### Tips

These tips just are observations and proposal. Maybe those will not be the solution but can help you to reach to its. Because you're not sharing all the scope and definition for this form component. Is not clear if you're using a statefull or stateless component.

**1.** You should consider to refactor both switch event handlers. Because its seems like like you are not updating the state as the rigth way. You should use the callback function for the setState. Following your convention, should look like this

[image]

Checking this line, please check the screenshot.

[image]

**2.** You should avoid and be carefull to setting values to the props. **Props are inmutable and readables**. Instead, you can move this to a local state. You can take a look at [the react site explanation](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-is-the-difference-between-state-and-props)

> ***Please share more scope of your issue. This way you can receive more help from the community***

*Regards.*

Comment: Important - I'm using antd designs for the component library. Then use class componenet. I will update the scope of my issue give me a 1 min for that

Comment: now you can check I update my code